# Не понимаю для чего это строка config[config_name].init_app(app) в коде

Tags: python, flask, config

```
.....config.py.....
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET KEY') or 'kbufktutyl'
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass

config = {
    'default' : Config
}
.....__init__.py.....
def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)
```

Метод `init_app(app)` конфиг. файла ничего не делает, зачем он в коде в `__init__.py`? И для чего на практике этот статический метод в конфиг. файле? Понятно только, что для инициализации, а дальше туман.

Comment: Видимо предполагается, что в будущем метод будет допилен. В целом статические методы отличаются от обычных тем, что они могут вызываться без создания объекта, т.е. как `Config.init(app)` в данном случае.

Comment: А для какой цели его использовать возможно? В учебники написано, что там можно определять классы конфигураций и в нем выполнять операции по инициализации в зависимости от выбранной конфигурации, но для чего? В учебнике он так и остался пустым.

Comment: В данном случае это может быть например инициализация приложения из файла. Статический метод может быть какой-то функцией, которая напрямую не взаимодействует с объектом класса, в котором находится, но по смыслу возможно как-то относится к классу, поэтому его включили в него.

Comment: @АлиКартоев, можно создать базовый класс конфига, а от него наследовать например DebugConfig и ProductionConfig, и простой подменой применить нужные настройки